# Use Windows 2016 Storage Replica for SQL Server failover cluster instance

Tags: sql-server, clustering, san, windows-server

We have two standalone servers with local storage. Based on our needs we have determined that we need to use AlwaysOn failover cluster instances.

Can we use the "[Storage Replica overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/storage-replica-overview)" feature of Windows Server 2016 to create the failover cluster?

We also open to buy new SAN storage. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frequently Asked Questions about Storage Replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/storage-replica-frequently-asked-questions) specifically mentions using it for a SQL Server FCI.  [Business continuity and database recovery - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/sql-server-business-continuity-dr) also mentions it specifically.

I've also found other non-Microsoft articles ([this one, in particular](http://fard-solutions.com/sql-server-strech-cluster-windows-server-storage-replica/)) mentioning it as well.

This, along with the fact that SQL Server doesn't know or care about the underlying storage as long as it presented as cluster storage, indicates that the answer is yes, it will work.

Comment: another option could be https://us.sios.com/products/sios-datakeeper/

Comment: Yes, there are a number of third party products that provide a replicated cluster storage resource.  Double-Take GeoCluster is another one.